# Mysql Recursive Query - get all parent-child relationship

Tags: mysql, sql

I have table with below data.

```
id|child
1|2
1|3
1|4
2|6
2|7
3|9
6|10
6|11
9|12
9|13
10|14
10|15
17|18
19|20
```

I need to fetch the data like below. i.e all parent child relationship for a id.

Here I have select all childs recursively for parent id "1"

```
id|all_child_id
1|2,3,4
2|6,7
3|9
6|10,11
9|12,13
10|14,15
```

I am looking for "WITH RECURSIVE" which is not supported my Mysql. Can someone help me how to write such recursive query where depth must not be any constraint.

Comment: You need to write a stored procedure or do it in your programming language. It's not possible with a single SQL query in MySQL.

Comment: @vhu - i tried this but not getting results as i want.

Comment: I'm not saying that the answers in that question would solution to your problem, but just that it's a duplicate question.

Answer (score 3):

What your expected output shows, can be achieved by using `group_concat`

```
select parent, group_concat(child)
from table
group by parent
```

[fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/43a4b1/2)

Answer (score 0):

try this ,

```
SELECT p.id, GROUP_CONCAT(c.child) AS all_child_id FROM parent p left JOIN 
child c WHERE p.id=c.child GROUP BY p.id
```

Comment: there is single table -- not two tables